# Can't debug dotnet core 1.0 console app form VS 2015 patch 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, console-application

If I just create a dotnet core console application and hit debug I get this message. Any clue?

```
Unable to start program 'C:\progream files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'

unrecognized error occurred in the windows web services"
```

Comment: Did you also install the .Net Core SDK and the Visual Studio Tools for .Net Core in addition to the Visual Studio Update 3?

Comment: @Rosenheimer , yeah I installed the latest .net core 1.0.0 sdk preview 2 and .net core 1.0.0 vs 2015 tooling preview 2, and vs 2015 update 3.

Comment: Turned out to be a problem with Sophos.